# Need to stop the Image rotation when mouse over it

Tags: php, html, css, image-rotation

In my page having an image which is in rotation. Initially if i load the page it will rotate automatically, but I need to stop rotation when cursor over it, if i move the cursor it again need to start the rotation

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more information next time. :)

```
img:hover
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: please vote up or select this as best answr, much appreciated:)